# Knockout Array Filter on more than 1 Observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observableArray which I pass through the `arrayFilter` to return a filtered set. But I'm only doing it for 1 observable at the moment. How can I add a second observable:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.complaints(), function (complaint) {
    return complaint.RaisedBy == self.currentUser();
});
```

So I also want to filter based on the `Code` property of my `complaint` object:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.complaints(), function (complaint) {
    return complaint.Code == self.currentCode();
});
```

How can I combine them two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.complaints(), function (complaint) {
    return complaint.Code == self.currentCode() && complaint.RaisedBy == self.currentUser();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. no I didnt think of that for some reason.. Stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
self.myDependantObservable = ko.computed(function(){
   var currentUser = self.currentUser();
   var currentCode = self.currentCode();

   return result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.complaints(), function (complaint) {
     return (complaint.RaisedBy == currentUser && complaint.Code == currentCode);
   });

});
```